# Using ssh keys to push to multiple github repos within gitlab CI

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I am trying to clone and update several github repos within one gitlab job in my pipeline. I have several ssh keys set up with the repos and the public keys are stored in my ci variables. I want to put this setup in the `before_script`. The initial approach in the code below did not work.

```
    - "which ssh-agent || ( apt-get update -y && apt-get install openssh-client -y )"
    - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
    - echo "$KEY1" | tr -d '\r' | ssh-add - > /dev/null
    - echo "$KEY2" | tr -d '\r' | ssh-add - > /dev/null
    - echo "$KEY3" | tr -d '\r' | ssh-add - > /dev/null
    - echo "$KEY4" | tr -d '\r' | ssh-add - > /dev/null
    - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
    - chmod 700 ~/.ssh
    - '[[ -f /.dockerenv ]] && echo -e "Host *\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n\n" > ~/.ssh/config'
    - git config user.email "test@test.com"
    - git config user.name "git-distribution-bot"
    - git config push.default simple
```

I want to set up something like this https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/654/how-to-create-and-configure-the-deployment-ssh-keys-for-a-gitlab-private-repository-in-your-ubuntu-server

Any help is appreciated!